# Why is my Django form returning the QueryDict without the submitted data?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views

The issue I'm having is that my form data returns *not None* nor *the form values I entered*, but simply just the usual csrf_token string and the button's value.

I verified this by printing `Form(response.POST).data`, which returns a QueryDict with just the csrf_token value and the value of the submit button:

`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['the token string'], 'save_customer': ['save_customer']}>`

Contrast this with the other working form's output that works. (I happen to be executing both procedures nearly identically):

`<QueryDict: {'tail': ['aasdf'], 'aircraft': ['asdf'], ...it's all here... 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['the token string'], 'add': ['add']}>`

So basically, my HTML file includes 2 forms. One form works, and the other doesn't. Having more than one form shouldn't be an issue, especially considering one form is in it's own separate container, and the other form resides in a modal. They do not share any "divs" with each other, nor any "parenting".

However, it should be noted that the 2nd form's corresponding view *is automatically executed* on page load and without any prior doing. The simple existence of the second form causes this to happen. I've deleted the javascript files, removed all traces of javascript functionality within the second form, and yet the view still gets called automatically. While this does appear to a separate issue, admittedly I'm too inexperienced to effectively determine the cause-effect relationship here.

Here's what my view, model, and HTML files look like:

**view.py**:

```py
def add(response):

    if response.method == "POST":
        form = Form(response.POST)
        # some other forms that works ...
        elif response.POST.get("save_customer"):
            # How is this getting called automatically on each page load anyway?
            if form.is_valid():
                customer = process_new_customer(form)
                customer.save()

    return render("executing this part works fine")

def process_new_customer(form):

    tail_number = form.data.get('tail')  # Doesn't exist
    first_name = form.data.get('first_name')  # Doesn't exist
    last_name = form.data.get('last_name')  # Doesn't exist

    customer = Customer(
        tail_number=tail_number,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
    )

    return customer  # This is None
```

**models.py**:

```py
class Customer(models.Model):


    tail_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)  # Not exactly required
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)  # but recommended

    customers = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tail_number)
```

**HTML**:
(This one is long, I feel the problem is more likely to lie in here somewhere)

```html
<form method="post" class="form_group border border-dark">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- A separate form in the same file that works -->
</form>


<!-- The 'submit' portion is at the bottom, not sure to what extent these other detail are relevant -->
<form id="saveCustomerInfoForm" method="POST" class="form_group">
  <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="row pad-top">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" id="first-name-id" oninput="enable_save_customer_button()">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" id="last-name-id" oninput="enable_save_customer_button()">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <br>
        <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend form-label-group">
        <div class="input-group-text">Tail #</div>
        </div>
            <input name="pseudo-tail" type="text" class="form-control" id="save-tail-text-id" placeholder="Not entered (this is a bug, please report it)" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend form-label-group">
        <div class="input-group-text">Aircraft type</div>
        </div>
            <input name="pseudo-tail" type="text" class="form-control" id="save-aircraft-text-id" placeholder="Not entered" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

    {% csrf_token %}  <!-- A second csrf_token that shouldn't be the issue -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel-button-id">Cancel</button>
        <!-- Button type "submit" causes Django view to be called -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add-todo" id="save-customer-button-id" name="save_customer" value="save_customer" formmethod="POST">Save customer info</button>
        <!-- An actual POST response depends on if it's specified in the form tag above -->
      </div>
</form>
```

So what should I be doing differently in order to be able to have 2 *working* forms on the same page? Is there any other information I can provide? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my own issue. The bottom line is that 'name' attributes need to be where your input fields are, and I was missing those. Django uses the name fields (not ID or value) to retrieve the inputted values of each field. It was an oversight on my part- the form did work a couple days ago, so it looks I removed the name attributes for testing purposes and forgot.

Furthermore, make sure you actually submit a *new* form when making these changes. This didn't solve my issue of the form appearing to be submitted/posted (whichever the correct terminology is) automatically from my view. But I did notice that the csrf_token remains consistent (along with any field data) until a new request is posted by the user. It may seem obvious, but just to err on the safe side for beginners like myself, make sure to actually tell Django that you made form changes.